spanners in interactive gt tables
When using the gt package, spanners disappear when I make the table interactive with opt_interactive(). How do I keep the spanner?
As a simple example, I use mtcars with an intended spanner. When created without interactivity the spanner displays, when created with interactivity the spanner disappears.
library(gt)
mtcars |> 
  gt() |> 
  tab_spanner(label = "example",
              columns = c(mpg, cyl))

But in this example, the spanner is gone:
library(gt)
mtcars |> 
  gt() |> 
  tab_spanner(label = "example",
              columns = c(mpg, cyl)) |> 
  opt_interactive()

What can I do to make the spanners reappear?

This has been fixed with gt 0.11.0!
